# Find top 10 values above Y threshold and spread across X

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Quick question

I have a series of data points defined in two lists as X and Y. I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to select (let's say) 10 values from X and Y which are not only above a particular value of Y (a threshold), but are also spread across values of X as much as possible. By 'spread', I mean maximising the delta between X for adjacent points.

For example:

If the Y threshold = 100 and the X range = 1-10, an ideal set of values would be.

```
[1,104]
[2.5,120]
[3,101]
[4.7,150]
[5.2,190]
[6.3,115]
etc
```

A non-ideal set would be:

```
[1,104]
[1.3,157]
[1.6,174]
[1.5,120]
[1.17,135]
Etc
```

Any thoughts would be most appreciated

Comment: Use `randint`? Btw, it's not actually clear what do you mean by 'good spread'

Comment: Define spread mathematically. For instance, maximize average delta_x for adjacent data points?

Comment: Y threshhold = 100 ?

Comment: @NeoWang good point. By spread I mean maximising the delta X for adjacent points. Ive edited my original question.

Comment: So, element of List X with index 3, and element of List Y with index 3 make a single Point ?

Comment: What makes two point adjacent ?

Comment: In your ideal set, you are not maximizing `delta_X` for adjacent points (assuming by adjacent you are refering to list index.
The ideal set would be - `[[1,104],[9.<something>,<something>],[<back to one.something>]...]`

Comment: i think you can convert these 2 lists to dictionary first and then easily work on them [something like this] (http://rextester.com/AWHI43872). I know this does not completely meet your requirement, but might guide you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

First extract the data points such that `Y > Threshold`.

Then sort on increasing `X`. Get `Xmin` and `Xmax` and compute 8 additional values of `X` equally spaced in this range, to form an increasing list `Z` (the "ideal" values).

Now scan both lists in parallel, as in a merge operation. Every time you move in the `Z` list, keep the corresponding `X` element.

CAUTION: this process can fail if the algorithm finds the same `X` corresponding to two different `Z`'s. Fixing this isn't so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to @Yves Daoust's solution, I write a script:

```
from itertools import combinations
def get_max_x_scatter(datapoints, y_threshold, no_of_points):
        # First exclude the data points that is below y_threshold
        candidates = filter(lambda x: x[1]>y_threshold, datapoints)
        if len(candidates)<no_of_points:
                print "Not enough data points"
                return
        # Sort the candidate data points by x 
        candidates_sorted_by_x = sorted(candidates, lambda m,n:int(m[0]-n[0]))
        # Get the x distance of 2 data points on remote ends
        distance = candidates_sorted_by_x[-1][0]-candidates_sorted_by_x[0][0]
        # Divide by the number of data points wanted, you get the expected average delta 
        avg = distance/(no_of_points-1)
        # Within the K data points, find n of them that is *most scattered*

        min_delta = distance * no_of_points # make sure the initial min is large enough
        result = None
        for combination in combinations(candidates_sorted_by_x, no_of_points):
                delta = 0.0
                for i in range(1, no_of_points):
                        gap = combination[i][0] - combination[i-1][0]
                        delta += abs(gap - avg)
                if delta < min_delta:
                        min_delta = delta
                        result = combination
        return result


dp = [
[1,104],
[1.3,157],
[1.6,174],
[1.5,120],
[1.17,135],
[2.5,120],
[3,101],
[4.7,150],
[5.2,190],
[6.3,115],
[2,23]]

print get_max_x_scatter(dp, 100, 5)

>>> ([1, 104], [1.6, 174], [3, 101], [4.7, 150], [6.3, 115])
```

This algorithm minimize the deviation of data points from average delta, it may or may not be what you want. But it can be described to be 'as scattered as possible'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should define "maximizing the spread across values of X" more precisely. Anyhow, let assume you a function `f(S)` that returns, for a set of point `S`, the `spread across values of X` of this set. You could try the following greedy algorithm (pseudocode below), that just select the potential values one after the other.

I assume your initial set of values comes as `(X_i, Y_i)`for `1 <= i <= n`.

```
Let S = empty list
Let i = 0
While |S| <= 10
    If (Y_i > threshold) add (X_i,Y_i) to S
    i++;
While i < n
    If Y_i >= threshold 
        Let j be such that X_j <= X_i <= X_{j+1}
        Let S_j = S, S_{j+1} = S;
        Remove (X_j, Y_j) from S_j and (X_{j+1}, Y_{j+1}) from S_{j+1}
        Add (X_i, Y_i) to S_j and to S_{j+1}
        If f(S_j) > f(S) let S = S_j
        If f(S_{j+1})> f(S) let S = S_{j+1}
    i++;
Return S
```

This would reduce the complexity to something like `p*n` where `p` is the number of values you want to select (assuming you keep `S` sorted and have a relatively fast way to compute `f`). I am not sure however whether this greedy algorithm yields an optimal solution. I would guess that it does at least for some reasonable forms of `f`.